# How to translate custom content block title?

Tags: 8, blocks

How do I properly translate custom content block titles?

Problem:
I've got a custom content block with just one CKeditor text field. I want to show the custom block title and the text field. When I place that block, the PLACED block title is copied from (but not referencing) the custom content block.

When a content translator later translates that custom content block, the PLACED block title is wrong/untranslated. Is there a way to reference the correctly translated, custom content block title in block placement? E.g. using tokens?

NOT allowed solution:
Giving translators access to block placement to translate the block placement is an absolute no-go. They are only allowed to use custom block library.

Unwanted workaround:
I know I could create an additional fake-title field and disable "Show title" in block placement. But I really hope I can avoid this, or I would have to modify all my existing block templates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use the title from the custom content block entity (not the title from the block placement config):

```
function mymodule_preprocess_block (&$variables) {
  if ($variables ['elements'] ['#base_plugin_id'] == 'block_content') {
    $variables ['label'] = $variables ['content'] ['#block_content'] ->label ();
  }
}
```

This also respects translations and does not require access to block placement for translators.

Comment: Not relevant to my question. I already have the translated block. The problem is that the translated block title is not used by block placement.

Comment: Thanks, the preprocessing was the key. I added a small if-condition to respect "Show title" setting `if ($variables['label']) { $variables['label'] = $variables['content']['#block_content']->label(); }`